# Subscripting Strings in django templates

Tags: python, django, string, django-templates, subscript

Is it possible to **subscript strings** in django templates ?

What i mean is doing

```
print "hello"[:3]
=> hel
```

in **django templates**.

Writing `{{ stringVar[:10] }}` throws

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[:10]'  from 'stringVar[:10]'
```

Comment: Incidentally the answer was an inbuilt filter. So I think I will remove the sentence "Is there an inbuilt way to do this other than writing filters ?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, but the syntax is slightly different as what you're used to. Use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#slice):

```
{{ stringVar|slice:":2" }}
```

This will give you the first 2 elements from the list (or the first two chars from a string).